# Never perhaps did any man suffer death with more justice, or deserve it less

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

[Source:](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=1&sr=) From Alexander Hamilton to Lieutenant Colonel John Laurens, 1780 October 11

> ... [Major John André] he ought to be considered as a spy and according to the laws and usages of nations to suffer death; which was executed two days after.
>   [11]   `Never perhaps did any man suffer` death **with more justice**, or deserve ***it*** less. The first step he took after his capture was to write a letter to General Washington conceived in terms of dignity without insolence and apology without meanness.<sup>[9](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=1&sr=#ARHN-01-02-02-0896-fn-0009)</sup>

'Perhaps' sounds like a [hedge word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_%28linguistics%29); so I just ignore it in this question. Perhaps (repetition intended) the cited text confuses me because [negatives still mangle my reading comprehension](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51324/8712).

1. What does **with more justice** mean?  Is this ambiguous?
1.1. That  `never ... did any man suffer` a more deserved, rightful death (because André was spying)?
1.2. Or that André suffered [= tolerated [(See ODO Defn 2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suffer)] death 'like a brave man' ?

2. If 1.2 is right, then is **justice** here the aptest word? Or did its meanings differ in the 1700s?

3. How do you determine or deduce the antecedent of ***it***?

Footnote: I tried a gloss from [p 8](https://books.google.com/books?id=CSiG7zgbQToC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22Never+perhaps+did+any+man+suffer+death+with+more+justice,+or+deserve+it+less%22&source=bl&ots=NFG2JOoS-a&sig=5U3zQSK7QVsX5V7YZjMLjy7zGZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jbz_VKroC5OGNoOggNAI&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%20suffer%20death%20with%20more%20justice%2C%20or%20deserve%20it%20less%22&f=false), *American Sympathy: Men, Friendship, and Literature in the New Nation*,  By [Caleb Crain PhD](http://www.steamthing.com/about-me). I first encountered the excerpt above on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Andr%C3%A9).

Comment: The two answers have thrown down a gauntlet of interpretation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Never perhaps did any man suffer death with more justice, or deserve
>   it less.*

1. In general, the phrase *with more justice* meant "more appropriately" close to the current sense of *justice* in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/justice):

> 1.1 The quality of being fair and reasonable:

This can be seen by examining the specific occurrences of the phrase in the [Corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20more%20justice&year_start=1700&year_end=1820&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20more%20justice%3B%2Cc0) from 1700-1820. As an example, from the 1797 [The Encyclopedia Britannica](https://books.google.com/books?id=aXxBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA180&dq=%22with%20more%20justice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=od3_VNP8FoapyAT5_IGoCg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22with%20more%20justice%22&f=false) entry under *Odontalgia, the Toothache*:

> The Peruvian bark has also been recommended, and perhaps with more
>   justice, on account [of] its tonic and antiseptic powers ; but very
>   often all these remedies will fail, and the only infallible cure is to
>   draw the tooth.

In this case any ambiguity would come from the internal reference, except that *or* establishes a clear comparison between the phrases *with more justice* and *deserve it less*. This comparison suggests that André [tolerated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suffer) a death sentence he did not deserve with the integrity of a gentleman. The larger context of [Hamilton's work,](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=1&sr=#ARHN-01-02-02-0896-fn-0009-ptr) the [monument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_John_Andre_Monument) erected to André in Tappan, New York, and the analysis of *[American Sympathy](https://books.google.com/books?id=CSiG7zgbQToC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%20suffer%20death%20with%20more%20justice,%20or%20deserve%20it%20less%22&source=bl&ots=NFG2JOoS-a&sig=5U3zQSK7QVsX5V7YZjMLjy7zGZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jbz_VKroC5OGNoOggNAI&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Never%20perhaps%20did%20any%20man%20suffer%20death%20with%20more%20justice%2C%20or%20deserve%20it%20less%22&f=false)*, all confirm this interpretation of Hamilton's sentiment.

2. If I were paraphrasing *with more justice* in this context, I would likely use *with more [integrity:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/integrity)*

> 1.1 The quality of being honest and having strong moral principles:

3. With the coordinating conjunction *or*, the predicate *deserve it* is coordinated with the predicate *suffer death* making *death* the antecedent of *it*. The construction also coordinates the adverb ***less*** with the adverbial prepositional phrase *with **more** justice* for the logical comparison.

---

ODO

books.google.com

Encyclopedia Britanica

en.wikipedia.org

Answer (score 1):

> *Never perhaps did any man suffer death with more justice, or deserve it less.*

I don't think that Hamilton intended any ambiguity here, but I think I see how the ambiguity might arise for a modern reader.

I believe that the meaning of *suffer* here is the first sense in [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193523?p=emailAwLl.IVjCrpWE&d=193523), namely:

> I. To undergo, endure.
>
> 1. *trans.* To have (something painful, distressing, or injurious) inflicted or imposed upon one; to submit to with pain, distress, or grief.
>
> a. pain, death, punishment, †judgement; hardship, disaster; grief, †sorrow, care.

*To suffer death* was a common and very old phrase in legal contexts. Melville riffed on it in [a chapter in his novel *White-Jacket*](http://www.online-literature.com/melville/white-jacket/70/).

I believe that in the phrase *with more justice,* the word *justice* takes sense 1.2 in ODO (no link, sorry, because I apparently am not allowed to link more than twice per post), namely,

> The administration of the law or authority in maintaining just behavior or treatment.

I don't think Hamilton intended the phrase *suffer death with more justice* to be ambiguous, or that it would have occurred to him that it could mean that André suffered "death like a brave man," but I think I see how a modern reader, not familiar with the phrase *suffer death,* might be confused.

The trouble is that although, grammatically speaking, the verb *suffer* in Hamilton's sentence is in the active voice, taking *death* as its object, the meaning of the word *suffer* is passive. The word *passive,* in fact, comes from the Latin word for "suffer" (OED). Hamilton wouldn't therefore have imagined that a reader might think that it was André who was displaying "more justice," because in Hamilton's mind, the action in the sentence was being performed not by André but by the authorities who were executing him. It was their action that was being performed with "more justice," that is, with greater adherence to the proper administration of the law.

Although it's plausible grammatically, I don't think it's quite viable to construe the sentence as meaning that André underwent his execution more appropriately, or with more fairness and reasonableness. Under such a construction, André would be showing appropriateness, fairness, or reasonableness toward death, and I'm not sure what it would mean to be fair or reasonable toward death, unless death is being personified, which it doesn't seem to be here.

As for the pronoun *it,* I think it **is** ambiguous, grammatically speaking, but doesn't impair Hamilton's meaning. *It,* as deployed in this sentence, can refer either to *death* or *justice,* but in André's case, death **was** justice; that is, death was the punishment that a due administration of the law demanded in a case of spying. So in Hamilton's mind, there's no possible misunderstanding for the reader to trip over.

Comment: +1 . I thank you deeply for your answer and welcome to ELU! I'm honoured to have a literary scholar answer my question. Out of curiosity, how did you realise my reference to you work in my question? I also ask this [here](http://superuser.com/q/888338/269574), if you don't mind.

Comment: You're welcome! Plain old google, I'm afraid, is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you again, especially for replying again. If interested, I reposted my question [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74874/72255). I hope to be enlightened from your expertise here in the future.

Comment: If André didn't *deserve* the death sentence, as Hamilton implies, how can he justify using *with more justice* referring to *proper administration of law*? Either André's mitigating circumstances stay the death penalty (as many wanted), or he actually deserved the death penalty. Hamilton's thesis: André died a *just* man trapped in the ignoble schemes of war, while Arnold escaped as a wicked traitor.